# Помогите с циклом while

Tags: php, while

```
interface DeckInterface {
    public function shuffle();
    
    public function dealCard(): Card;
}

class Card {
    private string $rank;
    private string $suit;
    public function __construct(string $rank, string $suit) {
         $this->rank = $rank;
         $this->suit = $suit;
    } 
    
    public function getRank(): string {
        return $this->rank;
    }
    
    public function getSuit():string {
        return $this->suit;
    }
}

class Deck implements DeckInterface {
    private array $card;
    private array $suits;
    private array $elements;
    
    public function __construct() {
        $this->suits = ['♥', '♦', '♣', '♠' ];
        $this->elements = ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'В', 'Д', 'К',  'Т'];
        
        foreach($this->elements as $rank) {
        foreach($this->suits as $suit) {
        //  $this->card[] = $rank . $suit;
            $this->card[] = new Card($rank, $suit);
        }
    }
    
    $this->shuffle();
 }      
        public function shuffle() {
            shuffle($this->card);
        }
        
        public function dealCard(): Card {
            return array_shift($this->card);

        }
        
        public function getCards() {
            return $this->card;
        }
   }
   
   
interface PlayerInterface {
    public function addCard($card);
    
    public function countCardInHand(): int;
}

class Player implements PlayerInterface {
    
    protected array $hand;
    
    public function __construct() {
        $this->hand =  [];
    }
    public function addCard($card) {
        $this->hand[] = $card;
    } 
    public function countCardInHand(): int {
        return count($this->hand);
    }
}

class Game {
    
    private Deck $deck;
    
    private Player $firstPlayer;
    
    private Player $secondPlayer;
    
    public function __construct() {
        
        $this->deck = new Deck();
        
        $this->firstPlayer = new Player();
        
        $this->secondPlayer = new Player();
    }
    public function play() {
    //  $this->dealCard() = $firstPlayer;
    //  $this->dealCard() = $secondPlayer;
        
        while($this->deck-> getCards()) {
            $this->hand[] = $card;
        }
}
}
$game = new Game();
var_dump($game->play());
//var_dump($hand);
//$player = new Player();
//var_dump($player->addCard('1'));
//var_dump($player->countCardInHand());
//$deck = new Deck();
//var_dump($deck);
//var_dump($hand->getCards());

  ["firstPlayer":"Game":private]=>
  object(Player)#39 (1) {
    ["hand":protected]=>
    array(0) {     -- тут берет карту
    }
  }
  ["secondPlayer":"Game":private]=>
  object(Player)#40 (1) {
    ["hand":protected]=>
    array(0) {         -- тут берет карту
    }
  }
}
```

Хотел чтобы тут было видно какие карты я беру. Вообще это игра пьяница насколько я помню. Так вот если убрать из var_dump play() можно посмотреть что выводиться. Нужно исправить цикл while я новичок поэтому помогите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так во первых в цикле while ты уже проверяешь остались ли карты в колоде, но если они закончились то циклу следует бы остановиться. Дальше в теле цикла бы чередовать выдачу карт каждому по очереди, короче ща покажу как я это всё вижу в коде

```
public function play() {
while (!empty($this->deck->getCards())) { // Проверяем, остались ли в колоде карты
    $this->firstPlayer->addCard($this->deck->dealCard()); // Даем карту первому игроку
    if (!empty($this->deck->getCards())) { // Проверяем, остались ли карты после предыдущей раздачи
        $this->secondPlayer->addCard($this->deck->dealCard()); // Даем карту второму игроку
    }
}
```

Обрати внимание, что я добавил проверку после того, как первый игрок получает карту. Это нужно для того, чтобы в случае, если карты закончатся после раздачи первому игроку, второй игрок не попытался взять карту из пустой колоды

По поводу вывода карт игроков после раздачи, надо бы сделать метод в классе Player. Допустим назовём его getHand()

```
public function getHand() {
    return $this->hand;
}
```

Далее делаем метод в классе Game где используем наш метод из класса Player таким образом:

```
public function getFirstPlayerHand() {
        return $this->firstPlayer->getHand();
    }
    
    public function getSecondPlayerHand() {
        return $this->secondPlayer->getHand();
    }
```

И получится у нас что-то вроде этого

```
$game->play(); // Сыграть в игру

// Вывести карты первого игрока
echo "Карты первого игрока:\n";
var_dump($game->getFirstPlayerHand());

// Вывести карты второго игрока
echo "Карты второго игрока:\n";
var_dump($game->getSecondPlayerHand());
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ очень сильно помогли!

Comment: Карты первого игрока:

Warning: Undefined variable $game in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 122

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFirstPlayerHand() on null in /home/user/scripts/code.php:122
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 122

Comment: Пишет что нужно вызвать

Comment: public function getFirstPlayerHand() {
        return $this->firstPlayer->getHand();
    }
    
    public function getSecondPlayerHand() {
        return $this->secondPlayer->getHand();
    }
 public function play() {

Comment: подставил выше public function play()

Comment: А все не надо у меня получилось устранить проблему, но появилась другая TheRetroHome в выводе команды выводиться примерно так: Карты первого игрока: от 1 до 17 и Карты второго игрока: от 1 до 17 мне нужно чтобы первый игрок и второй брали первой значение.

Comment: ты имеешь ввиду что хочешь чтоб карты тасовались? Не совсем понял если честно

Comment: Не я имею ввиду что каждый игрок берет по одной карте я делаю игру пьяницу